# Query Plan: Cost of querying on Id is over 8

Tags: soql, selectivity

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT Id FROM Visit WHERE Id = 'xxx'
```

The Query Plan result looks like below, does anybody have any idea on this?
[image: Query Plan Result]

Comment: Just a guess, so not an answer, but looks like TableScan row and Index row are swapped on the Cost column.